# ethereum/web3JS specific use case: Manage Multiple addresses/transactions from a single private key

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I want to know if the below things are possible with ethereum.

1. I want to generate multiple addresses against a single private key, where multiple users can deposit money. Like for each transaction, I would like to create a new public address against a master private key. Is that possible?
2. additionally, I would like to know how can I collect a list of transaction received by multiple ethereum address together?